# Parse XML and find all instances of a string

Tags: xml, powershell, csv

I'm working with an xml file that looks similar to the following. However it is the following thousands of times over. I will be using powershell to parse through the xml

I need to find the task name of all the tasks where the string "c:\" shows up. While this could be easy if there was only one area that the string might show up, it can quite literally show up all over the task. In this particular task I have put the C:\ in 4 different times.

I'm hoping to get an output of the task name, and the places that the given path was referenced...

```
<Task ID="00000000" Name="Task name goes here" Active="0" NextEID="22" CacheNames="random" AR="0" TT="COS">
        <Info>
            <Description>
            </Description>
            <Notes>
            </Notes>
        </Info>
        <Parameters>
            <moreParameters>C:\pathGoesHere</moreParameters>
        </Parameters>
        <Schedules/>
        <Source HostID="0" Type="FileSystem" Path="C:\path" FileMask="[Parm:parameter].txt" DeleteOrig="0" NewFilesOnly="0" SearchSubdirs="0" Unzip="0" RetryIfNoFiles="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefRescanSecs="1" UDMxFi="1" UDMxBy="1" ID="11"/>
        <For ID="13">
            <Destination HostID="000000" Type="siLock" FolderID="" FolderType="4" FolderName="Home/[Parm:parameter]/" Subject="" FileName="[OnlyName]_[YYYY][MM][DD].bai" UseOrigName="0" ForceDir="1" OverwriteOrig="1" UseRelativeSubdirs="1" Zip="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" UseDefUser="1" UseDefClientCert="1" ID="12"/>
            <If ID="14">
                <When>
                    <Criteria>
                        <comp a="[ErrorCodeFile]" test="NEQ" b="0"/>
                    </Criteria>
                    <UpdOrig Action="d" ID="15"/>
                    <Destination HostID="0000000000" Type="Share" Path="C:\anotherCPath" FileName="[Parm:parameter]_[YYYY][MM][DD].bai" UseOrigName="0" ForceDir="1" OverwriteOrig="1" UseRelativeSubdirs="1" Zip="0" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" ID="17"/>
                </When>
            </If>
        </For>
        <If ID="19">
            <When>
                <Criteria>
                    <comp a="[ErrorCodeTask]" test="NNE" b="0"/>
                </Criteria>
                <Email HostID="385322183" Subject="[TaskStatus]-[TaskName]" Message="" AddressTo="email@address.com" Attachment = "C:\path\" UseDefRetryCount="1" UseDefRetryTimeoutSecs="1" ID="20"/>
            </When>
        </If>
    </Task>
```

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assuming that XML located at `file.xml`, following `XPath` with returns you `Name` attribute:
String "C:\" could be at:

```
//Task[contains(text(), "C:\") or //*[contains(text(), "C:\")] or //*[@*[contains(., "C:\")]]]/@Name
```

Explanations:

- Text of `Task` tag
- Text of any children
- In any attribute of any children

PowerShell sample:

```
#read xml
$xml = [xml](gc -Encoding utf8 .\test.xml) 

#process it
$xml | 
   Select-Xml '//Task[contains(text(), "C:\") or //*[contains(text(), "C:\")] or //*[@*[contains(., "C:\")]]]/@Name' | 
   % { $_.Node."#text" }
```

Comment: i just watched this answer produce a text file of over 1400 records thus saving me hours and hours of manual work. looks like i can just take the rest of the week off :-P

Comment: I changed the code a tad `$parsedData = $xml | Select-Xml !'//Task[contains(text(), "C:\") or //*[contains(text(), "C:\")] or //*[@*[contains(., !"C:\")]]]/@Name' | % { $_.Node."#text" };
add-content "c:\path\tasksWithC.txt" $parsedData` Yet the text file simply contains a list of ALL of the tasks. Including ones that don't contain C:\

Comment: what if I were simply looking to write each individual <task> to it's own separate file, how could I go about doing that?

Comment: something like this: `gci -recurse -include *.xml | % { PARSE FILE HERE }`

Answer (score 1):

When you cast to [xml], you can access everything using a really nice "property" syntax.  Multiple nodes with the same tag will be exposed as arrays.  Then you can use the InnerXml property to get at the raw XML string defining the current node.  You then just need to do a simple "-like" match against your search string.

Assuming you have multiple "Task" nodes under a single "Tasks" node in one file:

```
$tasks = [xml] (Get-Content .\Tasks.xml)
$tasks.Tasks.Task |?{ $_.InnerXml -like '*C:\*' } | select -expand Name
```

Or, if there is a single Task node in each of multiple files:

```
dir *.xml |%{ [xml] (Get-Content $_) } |?{ $_.Task.InnerXml -like '*C:\*' } | select -expand Name
```

These will get you the task names.  Getting every line within the node which contains the search string is a bit trickier.  Here's a hacky regex approach (I know I know, don't parse XML with regex...).  Again, assuming a single Task node in each XML file:

```
$taskXmls = dir *.xml |%{ [xml](Get-Content $_) }

foreach($taskXml in $taskXmls)
{
   if($taskXml.Task.InnerXml -like '*C:\*')
   {
       $hits = [Regex]::Matches($taskXml.Task.InnerXml, '<[^<]*C:\\[^>]*>')
       $hitList = $null
       if($hits)
       {
            $hitList = $hits | select -expand Value
       }
       new-object psobject -prop @{TaskName = $taskXml.Task.Name; Hits = $hitList}
   }
}
```